# How to add a covariate to a contingency analysis?

Tags: chi-squared-test, poisson-regression, predictor, contingency-tables, log-linear

**Scenario**

Consider you ask kids whether or not they like guns (yes/no answer). You also ask them whether they watched an action movie in the past two days.

Then, you are willing to see if there is any correlation between the two, perform a contingency analysis (eventually a Chi square test) and find a significant correlation between the two variables.

You realize however that most kids that declare liking guns are boys. Luckily, you know the gender of each kid interviewed and can include gender as a covariate.

**Question**

Generally speaking, how to add a covariate in a contingency analysis?

For the above example, I could imagine doing a logistic regression with "liking guns" as response variable. What if the variables can take several values. For example what if the question instead was "Who is your favourite actor?" and the question was "What type of movie have you last watch?"?

Is there a standard procedure for adding a covariate in a contingency analysis?

Answer (score 2):

In your example, I would have just used a logistic regression. If there are more than two alternatives for the response, look into some variant of multinomial logistic regression (search this site). More than two alternatives for the predictor is no problem.

But, for the general question. Chi-square analysis could be developed for multi-way contingency tables, but there would be very many different possibilities. A general framework is *log-linear modeling*, see [this text by Fienberg](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00FB2RTMY) which is accessible.  Here is [a web pdf](http://web.ntpu.edu.tw/~cflin/Teach/Cate/06CateUEN05ThreeWayPPT.pdf) with interesting examples.

And [here](http://www.uni-kiel.de/psychologie/rexrepos/posts/logLinear.html) you can find good, detailed example with the inbuilt `UCBAdmissions` dataset from R, building on this [well-known paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/1739581.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3Ace153cbbe0e5fea084e3c82a33d55097&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) by P. J. Bickel, E. A. Hammel and J. W. O'Connell.